# How do I read the markings on a Mitsuba capacitor?

Tags: capacitor

I'm trying to identify a suitable replacement capacitor for use in a relay. The relay is by Mitsuba and uses a Mitsuba capacitor, which appears to print different notation on it than I have found in guides or SE questions so far.

My guess is this is a 3uF capacitor based on the markings, which seeks a bit strange given its size (~2cm long by ~1cm in diameter). Here are the markings:

85(degrees) 8 (2) 3U

There is also an encircled "4 " down the side, but not where the printed strip indicating the negative pin is.

Comment: How about a picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I can't provide a definitive answer, I would vote for 3uF as well. I found some example of 10x20mm 3uF capacitor on internet (e.g. [here](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/87/Bus_Elx_DS_4308_M_Series-7492.pdf)), so this seems to corroborate this hypothesis.